# Como recuperar o número de commits feito por uma pessoa?

Tags: git

Qual o comando Git para recuperar o número de *commits* feitos por um determinado programador?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apenas um comando é suficiente para obter o resultado total de commits de todos os autores:

```
git shortlog -n -s
```

Saída:

```
9  paulomartinhago
1  Lucas Miguel
```

Outra forma de obter um resultado, agora por author:

```
git shortlog -n --author=paulomartinhago
```

Saída:

```
paulomartinhago (9):
      Demo commit 9
      Demo commit 8
      Demo commit 7
      Demo commit 6
      Demo commit 5
      Demo commit 4
      Demo commit 3
      Demo commit 2
      Demo commit 1
```

Ou da seguinte forma, sem listar os commits:

```
git shortlog -n -s --author=paulomartinhago
```

Saída:

```
9  paulomartinhago
```